# custom-set-faces common color variables

Tags: faces, custom

I want to fine-tune my syntax highlighting, and have created a separate `colors.el` file that gets loaded around the beginning of `init.el`. I often use the same color for multiple entries, and it gets difficult to keep track of them all, so I want to define a bunch of common colors as variables at the top of the file, something like this:

```lisp
(setq myblue "DodgerBlue1")

(custom-set-faces
 '(link ((:t (:foreground myblue)))))
```

This keeps giving me a "Wrong type argument: stringp, blue" error on load.

I only have a surface-level understanding of how Lisp works. What would be the proper way to expand `blue` into a literal string before `custom-set-faces` is evaluated? Do I need a macro for this? Please help me understand how to make this work.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Try something like (custom-set-faces `(link ((:t (:foreground ',myblue)))))

Comment: Also, be aware that there is already a standard library named `colors.el`. You might want to choose a different name for yours.

Comment: @Drew I think you made a typo, after trying some variations the one that worked was `(custom-set-faces <backquote>(link ((t (:foreground ,myblue)))))`

Comment: Yes, you don't need to quote the inserted value, which is a string. (Habit - it's more common to need to quote the value of the eval'd sexp, as a further evaluation of the result is common.